# Hard to work with multiple layouts in android xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

Im trying to work with google android game sample, But the game has a single activity and single xml layout.

The XML has many linearlayout, Each represents a screen in the game. For example, If i click the "Play" Button, The activity will disable all layouts for visibility and enable the "Play screen" layout for visibility.

I cant seperate the main activity because its cause me many problems in my project (Sharing viarables with activities). So i think that i need to stay with one activity and one xml.

The main problem is that in android studio i cant see the xml design.
The bottom line I want to design my game easily with android studio and continue use my sample project.

Any idea the make my life easier?

Thanks a lot!

[image]
The xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- SIGN-IN SCREEN -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/screen_sign_in" style="@style/LLScreen">
        <TextView style="@style/GameTitle" />
        <TextView style="@style/GameBlurb" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/button_single_player"
            style="@style/MainScreenButton"
            android:text="@string/single_player" />
        <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton android:id="@+id/button_sign_in"
            style="@style/SignInButton" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- MAIN SCREEN -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/screen_main" style="@style/LLScreen">
        <TextView style="@style/GameTitle" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/button_single_player_2"
            style="@style/MainScreenButton"
            android:text="@string/single_player" />
        <TextView style="@style/MainScreenButtonBlurb"
            android:text="@string/single_player_explanation" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/button_quick_game"
            style="@style/MainScreenButton"
            android:text="@string/quick_game" />
        <TextView style="@style/MainScreenButtonBlurb"
            android:text="@string/quick_game_explanation" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/button_invite_players"
            style="@style/MainScreenButton"
            android:text="@string/invite_players" />
        <TextView style="@style/MainScreenButtonBlurb"
            android:text="@string/invite_players_explanation" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/button_see_invitations"
            style="@style/MainScreenButton"
            android:text="@string/see_invitations" />
        <TextView style="@style/MainScreenButtonBlurb"
            android:text="@string/see_invitations_explanation" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/button_sign_out"
            style="@style/SignOutButton"
            android:text="@string/sign_out" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- INVITATION POPUP -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/invitation_popup" style="@style/InvPopup">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/incoming_invitation_text" style="@style/InvPopupText" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/button_accept_popup_invitation"
            style="@style/InvPopupButton"
            android:text="@string/accept_popup_invite" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- "PLEASE WAIT" SCREEN -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/screen_wait" style="@style/LLScreen">
        <TextView style="@style/Blurb" android:text="@string/please_wait" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- GAMEPLAY SCREEN -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/screen_game" style="@style/LLScreen">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/instructions"
            style="@style/Instructions" android:text="@string/instructions" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/my_score" style="@style/ScoreDisplay" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/button_click_me"
                style="@style/GameButton"
                android:text="@string/click_me"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/countdown" style="@style/FigureLabel" />

        <LinearLayout style="@style/ScoresBox">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/score0" style="@style/ScoreText" />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/score1" style="@style/ScoreText" />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/score2" style="@style/ScoreText" />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/score3" style="@style/ScoreText" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**EDIT-** I solved the problem, I just needed to add   `android:visibility="visible"` to the layout. Thanks.

Comment: This is sort of an odd design, where did you get this code?

Comment: @DillonBurton https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples

Comment: Check out the answers below. I get that doing it this way works, but it makes it really difficult to edit individual screens if you put everything in the same frame layout.

Comment: @DillonBurton - Look at my answer. Its easy now.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid nested Layouts, you should use `ConstraintLayout` instead. 
It allows you to align each `View` with rules based on other `Views` and even based on the parent layout.

But to use it, you have to add the dependency in your `gradle.build` file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

And the `Maven Repository` in your global gradle file:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
```

Here is a sample:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView33"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView34"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textView33"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView33" />
```

To learn more about it :

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You put your root layout `FrameLayout` in comment that's why you don't see anything.

Remove `<!--` in second line.

Comment: I removed a note from the xml just for the stack question, But forgot the <!--. On the real code its fine (<!-- .... -->. Also edit in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, I just needed to add  android:visibility="visible" to the layout. Thanks.